# Why do we have to forcefully use the bootstrap navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

I believe that this component is very problematic, it has many classes, and it is easily disbanded.
Would not it be much easier to use div with col and rows to control it in a simpler way?

Of course we could use some indispensable classes like fixed, but actually I think that navbar is very complicated. Are browsers very sensitive and could cause errors if there is no nav tag?

Excuse me if my question is very basic, but I try to learn on my own, and there are concepts that I do not know how to find them. Again an apology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing forceful unless you are working under someone. You can design your own stuff and no need to depend on bootstrap.

The only thing is bootstrap makes the coding faster as you need not work on the css or js part.

I started with bootstrap but currently, I have abandoned completly due to its extra codes and complexity.

Comment: Thanks for help! no more nav, navbar classes, tags etc etc...I created my own  nav. Thanks again!